# How does the operating system know which application to send the mouse event to?

Tags: operating-system, mouseevent

Because there could possibly be so many windows open at different spots. Some windows are active some are not, how does the OS delegate the mouse event based on where the application window is? I'm a little lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OS (or a dedicated program that comes as part of it) keeps track of the windows (their locations, sizes, depth w.r.t. other windows, state of "activeness") and the cursor position and can figure out which window is right below the mouse pointer. And that's all there is.

Answer (score 0):

System call is made by software to OS, so OS returns response to software not to mouse, If windows are from same software it still applies. Softwares are managed in table in background.

```
id, path, request
1, c:\word.exe, 2
2, c:\word.exe, 3
```

so basicaly OS knows from where the request was made. "Operating System Concepts Essentials" covers questions like these.